# Flash Canvas: Loading a URL into a Movieclip

Tags: flash, url, html5-canvas, loading, flashcanvas

I'm working on a project using Flash Canvas. The interface and most of the content has been created and performs as needed. At some point I'd like to grant the user the possibility to upload custom HTML and have it parse through to a blank movieclip (titled custom_html) so that it displays as one of the available emails.

I know how to do this with Flash and Javascript separately, but it has become a challenge in Flash CC Canvas building. Is my code correct or is there an easier way to accomplish this?

In the blank movieclip my code is as follows:

```
this.stop();

var url = 'http://example.com';

this.on("load", function() {
    this.location = url;
});
```